# How to prevent flexboxes from shrinking?

Tags: flexbox

I have two flexboxes which shrink on height change and nested content gets overlapped.
How to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> just add `flex-shrink:0` to your element and the flexbox will stop shrinking.

```html
<div class="flx">
    Some Content
</div>

<div class="flx">
    Some Content
</div>

<style>
    .flx{
        display: flex;
        flex-shrink: 0;
    }
</style>
```